# how to disable TextView content change according the the view width in android

Tags: android, textview

i'm creating a map using a Relative layout. on this map i have icons with a text above them.
to create those icons i used TextView with a drawble in the bottom in order to use as less views as possible. 
this map have a zoom option and as a result an icon can get outside of the screen. my problem is
when the TextView is getting out of the right side of the screen the TextView pushes the image and the text to the left so that there right side will stay on the screen and the left side will be out. any one have any idea how can i disable that change? so that the text will never change.